# invertible operator Sobolev space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let $T:H_0^2(D)\rightarrow H_0^2(D)$ a linear bounded operator defined via the sesqulinear form $(Tu,v)=a(u,v):=\int_{D}\Delta u\Delta v dx$. I have shown that T is coercive and self-adjoint. How can i proove that T is invertible;
thanks

Comment: Via Lax-Milgram's lemma, I guess.

Comment: it is enought to prove that T is bounded from below, which i could not prove. Also T is invertible if it is bijective. I tried to show that T is surjective (the injectivity is not difficult) but i could not..

Comment: Have a look at the analogous problem for the form $$\int \nabla u \cdot \nabla v.$$ Try to follow the same lines. You'll only need to apply twice the Poincaré's inequality.

Comment: Is the notation $(\cdot,\cdot)$ stands for inner product?

Comment: i think that t is indeed bounded from below from the coercivity:

Comment: $C||u||^2_{H_0^2}\leq a(u,u)=(Tu,u)_{H_0^2}\leq||u||_{H-0^2}||Tu||_{H_0^2}\ \Rightarrow ||Tu||_{H_0^2}\geq c||u||_{H_0^2}$